# Find position in file by character number

Tags: buffers, motion

When an error occur in compiling a program in Ghostscript, the error message  gives a "Current file position is ..." with a number. I use emacs to edit the program file, so I would like to be able easily to find that position in the file (if that is indeed what it is). Please how do I do that?

Sorry I can't find a more appropriate tag.

Comment: Depending on what is that number, e.g., 47 (line, character-position, etc) you can do `M-x goto-line 47` or `M-x-goto-char 47`.

Comment: @Name: Please consider posting that as an answer. You might want to also mention `next-error`, though it is only available for some error-reporting contexts.

Answer (score 18):

Depending on what is that number, e.g., 47 (line, character-position, etc) you can do M-x goto-line 47 or M-x-goto-char 47.

Comment: It might be useful to know that `goto-char` is bound to `M-g c`, and `goto-line` is `M-g M-g`.

Comment: Thank you Name and jimg, that's what I wanted. I would like to mark one of these as the answer but I don't have enough credit on this site.

Comment: @HarryWeston : you should be able to accept the answer.