# Reading at buffer position 2767`

Tags: debugging

I got such a error report  but confused with 'position 2767`

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable |)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-518868> nil "/home/me/.emacs.d/lisp/init-company.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/me/.emacs.d/lisp/init-company.el" "/home/me/.emacs.d/lisp/init-company.el" nil t)
  #<subr require>(init-company)
  apply(#<subr require> init-company nil)
  (prog1 (apply orig feature args) (if (and (not already-loaded) (memq feature features)) (progn (let ((time (sanityinc/time-subtract-millis (current-time) require-start-time))) (add-to-list 'sanityinc/require-times (list feature require-start-time time) t)))))
  (let* ((already-loaded (memq feature features)) (require-start-time (and (not already-loaded) (current-time)))) (prog1 (apply orig feature args) (if (and (not already-loaded) (memq feature features)) (progn (let ((time (sanityinc/time-subtract-millis (current-time) require-start-time))) (add-to-list 'sanityinc/require-times (list feature require-start-time time) t))))))
  sanityinc/require-times-wrapper(#<subr require> init-company)
  apply(sanityinc/require-times-wrapper #<subr require> init-company)
  require(init-company)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/me/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2767
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/me/.emacs.d/init.el" "/home/me/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/home/me/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1dda69>)()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

What does the  `Reading at buffer position 2`, and  `Reading at buffer position 2767`,

It seems not helpful because the max-line number is less than 500.

Comment: Open up `init-company.el` and see if you find a `|` symbol, probably near the very beginning of the file ...  Emacs is trying to read that `|` symbol and she is choking -- saying, wait a minute here, to the extent that `|` symbol is a variable, it has not been defined ....  In other words, it looks like you have a typographical error in your `init-company.el`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate to the exact location of the error you visit file `/home/me/.emacs.d/lisp/init-company.el` do [<kbd>M-x goto-char 2767 RET</kbd>](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Character-Motion.html).

In fact you might be able to just [switch to buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Buffer.html) `*load*-518868` (note the leading space!).

It appears that your file has a spurious `|` in it, which could be caused by an incomplete `git` merge.

See also [Find position in file by character number](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/29707/795)

Comment: yes, it was caused by git merge. The worst is that it seem impossible to locate it.

Comment: You should be able to detect it using `git diff`.