# Move cursor to an offset given by number of characters from the end of the buffer

Tags: buffers, motion

[This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29714/4084) shows how to position the cursor at an offset of a specified number of characters from the beginning of the buffer, namely by executing `M-x goto-char 47` (for an offset of 47 characters from the buffer's beginning). How can I position the cursor at an offset of a specified number of character from the buffer's *end*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using

```lisp
(goto-char (- (buffer-size) offset))
```

Where you replace 'offset' with some number.
(You can run the command using `M-:`)

Alternatively, you could first jump to the end of the buffer using `M->` end then jump back a certain number of characters using a numerical prefix by pressing `C-u 'some-number'` followed by `C-b`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to specify the buffer size as an argument to `goto-char` when using the `M-x-goto-char` version? Say, something along the lines of `M-x-goto-char-(-(buffer-size) 47)`?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you can easily [create a custom command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html) for it of course. ([here is another link](https://superuser.com/a/194215/919841) to how to create a command).